# Write Multiple Phone Number comma separated in US format

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher, phonenumberutils

I want to write the Phone number in US format with comma separated in edit text can anyone help me out in this case

I need to like phone number XXX-XXX-XXXX,XXX-XXX-XXXX and so on there can be multiple numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this attribute for edittext

```
android:inputType="phone|text"
```